# How To intercept Document in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I want to manipulate doc and change the token value for field(s) by prepending some value to each token. I am doing bulk update through DIH and also posting Documents through SOLRJ. I have replication factor as 2, so Replication should also work. The value that I want to prepend is there in the document as a separate field. I am interested to know the place where I can intercept the document before the indexing so that I can manipulate it. One of the option I can think of overriding DirectUpdateHandler2. Is this the right place?

I can do it by externally processing the document and passing it to SOLR But I want to do it inside SOLR.

Document fields are :

1. city:mumbai
2. RestaurantName:Talk About
3. Keywords:Cofee, Chines, South Indian, Bar

I want to index keywords as

1. mumbai_cofee
2. mumbai_Chines
3. mumbai_South Indian
4. mumbai_Bar

Comment: Are you having pattern where you would like to apply this. I would suggest  adding "PatternReplaceFilterFactory", to solve the problem.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti - that won't work because you can't pull in data from a different field within a Solr field analysis.

Comment: The JDBC driver is probably DIH's most popular `<datasource>`. If you're using that, then you can accomplish this in your embedded SQL queries.
If so, you _could_ use `CONCAT(RestaurantName,"_",city) AS restaurant, CONCAT(Keyword,"_",city) AS keyword` in your SQL query within your Solr's data import config.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't set up city as a filter/facet field instead of combining it with all the individual terms? Then your query could look something like: `fq=city:mumbai&q=keyword:bar`. If this would meet your needs it seems like an easier way to index the data and leaves you more flexible in how you query.

Comment: I have XML file as data source So one option is using XSLT transform the data such way that each of the field carry the first token as the city name. Then write a filter to do the manipulation. But with this I have to make sure that when I prepend it to the value it is resulted as separate token which might be a difficult task as each field will have different Tokenizer logic. I am trying to use term component for index browsing. If a city is selected then I should allow the user to see all the terms available for that city on that particular field. Hope this helps

Comment: Little correction I am prepending city not appending as mentioned in the original problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right place is an [Update Request Processor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor), you make sure you plug that in sorlconfig.xml into all udpate handlers you are using (including DIH), and the single URP will cover all updates.

In your java code in the URP you can easily get the value of a field and then prepend it to all the others in another field etc. This happens before the doc is indexed.

Comment: I have not see the API , But looks like a good place. I have to extend this (URP) class, right?

Comment: yes, look for example in the Solr test or online, there are many